# Why won't this config use DECLARE / FETCH on Amazon Redshift?

Tags: linux, odbc, redshift

In my home directory I have created:

`.odbcinst.ini`

```
[ODBC Drivers]
Amazon Redshift (x64)=Installed

[Amazon Redshift (x64)]
Description=Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver(64-bit)
Driver=/opt/amazon/redshiftodbc/lib/64/libamazonredshiftodbc64.so
```

`.odbc.ini`

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
db=Amazon Redshift (x64)

[db]
Driver=/opt/amazon/redshiftodbc/lib/64/libamazonredshiftodbc64.so
Server=xxxxxxx.c1xgxd2xxkxi.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com
Port=5439
Database=test_db
locale=en-US
UseDeclareFetch=1
Fetch=10000
Username=xxxxx
Pwd=xxxxx
```

`sample.qry`

```
select * from very_large_table;
```

Then when I run the command:

`isql -v db < sample.qry > /dev/null`

I check on the Redshift cluster, looking at the snapshot tables `stv_recents` and `stv_active_cursors`,  and the command runs directly. It does not create a cursor and start fetching 10000 rows at a time.

Based on my understanding and similar behavior I've seen elsewhere, it appears the DECLARE / FETCH is handled by the ODBC driver when `UseDeclareFetch` is enabled. I shouldn't have to do anything else special with the query I send. In fact, I used the ODBC Admin GUI on Windows and turned on these same options and a simple select statement sent to the database in an SSIS export resulted in a cursor being created.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm curious how exactly you "check on the Redshift cluster and the command runs directly. It does not create a cursor and start fetching". Can you please expand on this?

Comment: @mustaccio for the sake of brevity I did not include the queries proving that. But the information can be retrieved from stv_recents and stv_active_cursors. Hence the reason I indicated I’ve seen proper behavior elsewhere. Does this answer your question? I think the issue here might be that autocommit cannot be on. Some brief searching for isql shows methods for disabling autocommit (enable chained queries). But I’m seeing references to options and functionality that doesn’t exist in isql 2.3.6 that I can find. It’s like there are two different products we’re talking about.